# Вывести queryset с необходимыми данными

Tags: python, django

Есть 2 модели. Сократил для наглядности.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Document(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Предполагается, что под одним номером документа могут быть разные продукты. При выводе Document.objects.all() будет появляться:
document1 - product1
document1 - product2
document1 - product3
document2 - product1
итд
Как сделать, чтобы при получении queryset выводилось без повторов, например,
document1
document2
document3
итд

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. Эта модель не допускает связывания одного документа с многими продуктами. Конкретный документ ссылается на один продукт, а вот на определенный продукт может ссылаться много документов. Так что вопрос непонятен

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Видимо, да. Не могу до конца понять эти связи. В документации, например, написано про foreignkey и приводится пример с производителем машин и машинами. Связь обозначается как один ко многим. У производителя много машин. Но ведь и у машин много производителей. Почему именно такая связь? От какой печки плясать? Не нашел нигде подробной информации по этому моменту. Если есть какая-нибудь ссылка, буду благодарен))

Comment: Первое, что нашел https://metanit.com/sql/tutorial/1.3.php там пример описывает связь вроде адекватно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получить уникальные записи из queryset](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406922/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-queryset)