# Получить уникальные записи из queryset

Tags: python, django

Есть модель.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

В одной накладной может быть несколько наименований товаров. При Document.objects.all() получаются все записи. Как можно получить queryset только с уникальными номерами накладных? Например, было:

```
№1 кружка
№1 вилка
№2 табурет
№2 стол
№3 мяч
```

Нужно, чтобы получалось:

```
№1
№2
№3
```

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от того, что вы уже задавали ?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1405627/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-queryset-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас в БД существуют несколько записей з одинаковым `number`? `Document` - это накладная? Если так, то это главная проблема. Должна быть одна запись для накладной. У вас не в ту сторону ассоциации. Не документ должен ссылаться на продукт, а продукт на документ (или если продукт представляет собой тип продукта, то нужна связь many-to-many), в любом случае в документ должна быть одна запись для накладной. Тогда и с выборкой не будет проблем.

Comment: Насколько я понял, все сделал . В общем-то все работает. В одной накладной несколько товаров. Просто при выводе выводятся накладные с повторяющимися номерами. Я убрал их с помощью тега ifchanged, но хотелось бы по-другому

Comment: Вы можете ответить на вопрос, что я задал: Document - это у вас накладная? Без этого нельзя по существу обсуждать проблему. Если вы игнорируете вопросы, то трудно будет вам помочь.

Comment: попробую м2м, спасибо

Comment: да, документ - накладная

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корень проблемы в том, что у вас неправильно смоделирована предметная область. Вам нужна схема типа такой:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class DocumentItem(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Для накладной у вас одна запись в таблице документов, и несколько записей в таблице позиций `DocumentItem`, которая связывает накладную и товар. В этом случае `Document.objects.all()` вернет накладные без повторений.

Comment: Да, все верно, спасибо Доходчиво.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать distinct()

```
Document.objects.order_by('number').distinct()
```

Comment: distinct вроде не работает с sqlite